# How does concurrent.futures.as_completed work?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I'm learning about python concurrency and I was introduced with the concept of futures. I read that `as_completed()` takes an iterable of futures and yields them as they are done.

I want to know how it works internally. Is it yielding completed tasks (futures) immediately? A naive approach would be to iterate all futures and examine each and every future using `done()`, but this is inefficient.

So what's the magic behind this function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> I want to know how it works internally.

`as_completed` sets up a callback to fire when the future is done, doing so for all the futures it receives. (It uses an internal API equivalent to [`add_done_callback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.add_done_callback) for this purpose.) When any of the futures completes, `as_completed` is notified by its callback being run. The callback runs in whatever thread it was that completed the future, so it only sets an [event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects), which is shared by all callbacks, and which `as_completed` sleeps on. Once woken up by the event, `as_completed` immediately yields the finished future. This is how `as_completed` ensures that futures are yielded as they are completed, regardless of the order in which that happens. After yielding, the event is cleared and the waiting is repeated until all the futures are done.

> Is it yielding completed tasks (futures) immediately?

Yes, that follows from both the [documented interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=as_completed#concurrent.futures.as_completed) and the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f85af035c5cb9a981f5e3164425f27cf73231b5f/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py#L200).

Comment: Nice edit ... was wondering about the callback in the original text.

Comment: What happens if one of the coroutines terminates with an exception? Would that exception interrupt on the iteration line, when you await it later, or would it return it like `gather()` does?

Comment: nvm, tested it. Errors show up in the line where you await the available coroutine.

Comment: @Gloweye There are no coroutines here, this answer (and the question) is about `concurrent.futures.as_completed`, which deals with multi-threading, and is unrelated to asyncio.

Comment: Whoops, that'll teach me to read the tags next time. Apologies!